# get who created specific IAM user which is deleted now

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-iam

i want to check who create specific IAM user . how to get that from logs , can i use cloudtrail for this matter , FYI this IAM user is deleted now

Comment: Yes, you can use cloudtrial.

Comment: how to check this from cloudtrail